# ansible check max number list

Tags: filter, ansible, max

I am having issues with script in Ansible. I want to check the last sequence number the route-map in Cisco NXOS and I did the next:

My idea was to show the output and then, with map('regex_replace") remove all except the numbers.

Inside the role:

vars file:

```yaml
sequence: 10
```

tasks file:

```yaml
---
- name: check route-map
  nxos_command:
    commands: sh route-map |inc TEST-MAP
  register: output
- name: Calculate max number
  set_fact:
    max_seq_number: |
      {{ output.stdout_lines[0]  | map ('regex_replace','route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence','') | list |max}}
- name: Calculate number to use
  set_fact:
    sum: "{{ (max_seq_number |int) + (sequence |int)}}"
```

That it works but if the number of prefixes is more than 90 it fails.

This is the result:

```yaml
    "stdout_lines": [
        [
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 1 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 10 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 20 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 30 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 40 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 50 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 60 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 70 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 80 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 90 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 100 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 110 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 120 ",
            "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 130"
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [checks : Calculate max number] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /ansible/Config-Generator/roles/checks/tasks/Route-map-SequenceNumber.yml:6
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "**max_seq_number": " 90 \n"**
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [checks : Calculate number to use] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /ansible/Config-Generator/roles/checks/tasks/Route-map-SequenceNumber.yml:10
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "sum": "100"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Does anyone know why the Max number is 90 instead of 130?

If I use numbers until 90 it works perfectly, but more than 100 it does not work. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Please edit your question and format it correctly, more specifically the code blocks and the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing your values as string so the result is totally expected. "90" (starts with `9`) is further in the alphabet than "130" (starts with `1`).

You need to compare as int to get the greater int value.

The following shows the differences with the solution:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # simple one-liner with your original data for demo
    output: {"stdout_lines": [["route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 1 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 10 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 20 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 30 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 40 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 50 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 60 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 70 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 80 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 90 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 100 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 110 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 120 ", "route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence 130"]]}

  tasks:
    - name: show max string value
      debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
            output.stdout_lines[0]
            | map ('regex_replace','route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence (\d+).*','\1')
            | max
          }}

    - name: show max int value
      debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
            output.stdout_lines[0]
            | map ('regex_replace','route-map TEST-MAP, permit, sequence (\d+).*','\1')
            | map('int')
            | max
          }}
```

which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [show max string value] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "90"
}

TASK [show max int value] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "130"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```